# How can I test a scroll event based on useRef?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I am trying to writing unit-test for this code snippet using RTL and Jest. However, I cannot test the scroll part. I do not want to focus on implementation details but I think it should be tested. I tried to mock useRef but it did not help and not a good practice. How can write unit test for scrolling?

```
const Step = ({ steps, currentStep, setCurrentStep, dynamicScroll }) => {
  const stepsRef = useRef([]);
  const mainRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!dynamicScroll || currentStep >= steps.length) return;
    let scrollWidth = 24 * currentStep;
    for (let i = 0; i < currentStep; i++) {
      scrollWidth += stepsRef.current[i].scrollWidth;
    }
    mainRef.current.scrollTo({
      left: scrollWidth,
      behavior: 'smooth',
    });
  }, [currentStep]);

  return (
    <div
      ref={mainRef}
      className={cx('w-full scrollbar-hide', {
        'overflow-x-auto': dynamicScroll,
      })}
      data-testid="step-main"
    >
      <div
        className={cx('flex items-center py-[5px] w-full ', {
          'w-fit': dynamicScroll,
        })}
      >
        {steps.map((step, index) => (
          <React.Fragment key={step}>
            <button
              label={step}
              type="button"
              className={cx(
                'text-gray cursor-pointer  before:content-[attr(label)] min-w-fit whitespace-nowrap before:font-semibold before:invisible before:block overflow-hidden before:h-0',
                {
                  '!text-gray-600 font-semibold': index === currentStep,
                  '!text-primary font-semibold': index < currentStep,
                }
              )}
              ref={(el) => {
                stepsRef.current[index] = el;
              }}
              onClick={() => setCurrentStep(index)}
            >
              {step}
            </button>
          </React.Fragment>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Step;
```

When I tried to render in test file, I got this `TypeError: mainRef.current.scrollTo is not a function`

Answer (score 0):

An approach would be to use the [fireEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-events/#fireevent) from react-testing-library and [spyOn](https://jestjs.io/docs/jest-object#jestspyonobject-methodname) from jest.

Something like that:

```
const container = getByTestId('step-main');
const scrollToSpy = jest.spyOn(container, 'scrollTo');

fireEvent.click(container.firstChild.children[1]); // test scrolling to next step or what you want to test

// your expect here
```

Comment: What refers `main` here? and when I try to render without any expectation I got `TypeError` that I mentioned since ref is not mocked.

Comment: would be the ````container````